# How I can get the actual final location of an object inside a geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have the following geometry node that sets the material to red if the geometry is in the negative axis and blue if positive

[image]

Now I have a different geometry node that simply displays the geometry of another object, in the case of the screenshot the cube in the negative axis is selected

[image]

As you can see this will make the first geometry node to ignore the final position of the object and it will display as red instead of blue.

I guess the problem here is that I shouldn't use "Self Object" to get the location, but I can't find how I can get the actual final location where the object is going to be displayed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, this is how dependency graph works. Since you have used the object, it has to be invoked before using it in node tree. So the geometry nodes of the object is calculated before instancing the object in the other object.

Here is the result if you set node tree "set_material" after replacing geometry:

[image]

Comment: but you are now applying the same geometry node twice right?

If I apply a transform in the geometry to red then it gets applied to the proxy too https://imgur.com/a/3GogYDb

Comment: @ellipticaldoor Right, but second one is after instancing

Comment: so do you think is not possible to do what I want to do without having to add more nodes?

Comment: You can set color in shader